# Flex : best way to avoid slide transition quirks

Tags: apache-flex

I have a custom viewstack that applies automatically a slide in/slide out effect when the view changes. Everything goes smoothly when the views are lightweight but becomes jumpy when the next view requires heavy rendering. 
Here are the relevant parts of the code :

```
        _showEffect  = new Parallel();
        _contentMove = new Move();
        _imageMove     = new Move();
        _showEffect.addChild(_contentMove);
        _showEffect.addChild(_imageMove);
        _showEffect.addEventListener(EffectEvent.EFFECT_END, effectEndHandler);
```

I apply the parallel effect to the showEffect of every view :

```
        vis.setStyle("showEffect", _showEffect);
```

I define the property of the moves depending on the direction of the animation, here to the left (where _views is my resident viewstack in the custom component) :

```
                _contentMove.xFrom = _views.width;
                _contentMove.xTo = 0;
                _contentMove.yFrom = 0;
                _contentMove.yTo = 0;

                _imageMove.xFrom = 0;
                _imageMove.xTo = -_views.width;
                _imageMove.yFrom = 0;
                _imageMove.yTo = 0;
```

_imageMove moves a screen image of the previous view which is set to visible when the animation starts and hidden when it ends.

I have tried some hacks like lengthening the duration of the animation when the next page has never been shown before but this is not quite generic as the required duration to have a smooth transition changes depending on the rendering requirements.

Isn't there any way like in other programming languages to force the layout/rendering process of the next page while it is still out of view ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Viewstack](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/Container.html#creationPolicy) has a creationPolicy property. By default this is set to  ContainerCreationPolicy.AUTO, which means the views are rendered as-needed. This explains why the view appears jumpy when switching to it. You can set the creationPolicy property to  ContainerCreationPolicy.ALL and it will force the ViewStack to prerender all of its views before they are loaded.

This will solve your problem but note that it will increase overall initialization time of your application because it will now be forced to render everything ahead of time.

Comment: Hi, actually I have already played around with the creationPolicy but it doesn't seem to help much. Setting a flag on the creationComplete event of the view shows that it is created before the transition. And locking the animation until the flag is set to true does not help either. Only once the page has been shown a first time will the transition run smoothly. Sometimes, the quirks even remain if the page is rendered dynamically depending on its data (ex: view with a datagrid or repeater).

Comment: (if it's still urgent) You've got `showEffect`, which triggers when `visibility` of your component is set to `true`. But when you create component firs time, `visibility` is set to `true` much earlier the component is fully constructed. Combine upper answer (creationPolicy) with default false `visibility` and handler on `creationComplete`, which sets visibility to `true`.